# error with navigation bar button animation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

The following attempts to make a navigation button and animate it, however I think I am missing something.

Please let me know where I went wrong.

Thank you!
This is in a custom UINavigationItem class

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    UIImage *myimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarFilter.png"];
    NSArray * imageArray  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarFilter.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarFilter1.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarFilter2.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarFilter3.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarFilter4.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarFilter5.png"],
                             nil];

    CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, myimage.size.width, myimage.size.height);

    UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
    [someButton setBackgroundImage:myimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIBarButtonItem *filterButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];

    someButton.imageView.animationImages =imageArray;
    someButton.imageView.animationDuration=2.0;
    someButton.imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeBottomLeft;

    [someButton.imageView startAnimating];

    self.rightBarButtonItem =filterButton;
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    NSArray * imageArray  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarFilter.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarFilter1.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarFilter2.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarFilter3.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarFilter4.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarFilter5.png"],
                         nil];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarFilter.png"]];

    imageView.animationImages =imageArray;
    imageView.animationDuration=1.5;

    UIButton *someButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    someButton.bounds=imageView.bounds;
    [someButton addSubview:imageView];

    UIBarButtonItem *filterButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];


    self.rightBarButtonItem =filterButton;
    [imageView startAnimating];


}
```